# Are there names for these subsets of rational numbers?

Tags: terminology

Rational numbers can be defined as: $$\left\{ \frac{p}{q} | p \in \Bbb{Z}; q \in \Bbb{Z}; q \neq 0 \right\}$$

Are there conventional or existing names for the sets where $q$ is a particular number?  For example:

$$\left\{ \frac{p}{4} | p \in \Bbb{Z}\right\}$$

If there aren't commonly used names, are there commonly used notations?

Comment: No, these sets of numbers have no particular name, but they are denoted as $\frac{1}{q}\Bbb{Z}$.

Comment: $\Bbb Z/4\,$ or $\,\Bbb Z:4\,$ or  $\,\frac{1}4\,\Bbb Z\,$ or $\,4^{-1}\Bbb Z.\,$ What name or notation is used depends on the context, esp.. if it has more structure that just a set, e.g. a group, lattice, etc.

Comment: @Crostul, I edited my question so your comment should now qualify as an answer.

Comment: @BillDubuque, I edited my question so that your comment should now qualify as an answer.

Comment: @BillDubuque : for me $\mathbb Z/4$ are usually the integers mod 4 and $4^{-1} \mathbb Z$ the localization at 4 but I think it's probably matter of convention.

Comment: @N.H. Yes, such notation is overloaded so is context dependent.

Comment: @N.H. I thought the integers mod 4 were $\mathbb Z/4\mathbb Z$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notations include $q^{-1}\mathbb{Z}$,$\frac{1}{q}$,$\mathbb{Z}/p$. I would probably call it "Integers over p" or the likes.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is a generally-accepted name for such sets. Sometimes they are written as [dilations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homothetic_transformation) of $\mathbb{Z}$: $\dfrac12\mathbb{Z}$ or the like.

Do not confuse the set $\dfrac12\mathbb{Z}=\{\dfrac n2:\ n\in\mathbb{Z}\}$ with the [half-integers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-integer) $\{n+\dfrac12:\ n\in\mathbb{Z}\}$.

Comment: The latter would be written as $\mathbb Z+\dfrac12$, right?

Comment: @columbus8myhw: I prefer $\mathbb{Z}+{1/2}$ using the Minkowski sum, but each to her/his own.

Comment: You just said what I said, unless you meant $\mathbb Z+\{1/2\}$. (You need to use \} for brackets in LaTeX.)

Comment: @columbus8myhw: Thanks -- I was typing it out on my phone and missed the extra slashes.

Comment: For future reference, on the app, you can see how LaTeX renders your posts by clicking on it, hitting "More," and hitting "Render MathJax."$$e^{d/dx}f(x):=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{d^k}{dx^k}f(x)=f(x+1)$$